# about java and array search in a method and return data

Tags: java, arrays, methods

This is the program I have done so far. I am supposed to ask for a cashier to enter a price and y or n if its a pet. Then a method is supposed to calculate the discount if there is 5 or more items. The program I have is working except the return data of the discount method.

The error is 68: `error; cannot return a value from method whose result type is void.`

I am confused as why is the data void. If I take out the `return discount;` statement, then the program compile without error.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Assignment4
{
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        double[] prices = new double[1000];
        boolean[] isPet = new boolean[1000];
        double enterPrice = 0;
        int i = 0;
        String yesPet = "Y";
        int nItems = 0;
        do
        {
            String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter the price for the item: ");
            enterPrice = Integer.parseInt (input);

            prices[i] = enterPrice;

            String petOrNo = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Is this item a pet? Enter Y for pet and N for not pet.");

            if (petOrNo.equalsIgnoreCase(yesPet))
            {
                isPet[i] = true;
            }
            else
            {
                isPet[i] = false;
            }
            i = i+1;
            nItems = nItems + 1;
        } while (enterPrice != -1);
        //System.out.println(nItems);
    }

    public static void discount(double[] prices, boolean[] isPet, int nItems)
    {
        boolean found = false;
        double[] discount = new double[nItems];

        if (nItems > 6)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < nItems; i++)
            {
                if (isPet[i] = true)
                {
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (found = true)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < nItems; x++)
                {
                    if (isPet[x] = false)
                    {
                        int n = 0;
                        prices[x] = discount[n];
                        n = n + 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return discount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `discount` method needs to return a `double` array. Change

```
public static void discount(double[] prices, boolean[] isPet, int nItems) {
```

to

```
public static double[] discount(double[] prices, boolean[] isPet, int nItems) {
```

No values are assigned to any of the entries in `discount` array so every value will be `0.0`.

Comment: ty so much tried that out and it worked... people who asked me to do the program told me the method required is public static void discount... so that was given

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void discount(double[] prices, boolean[] isPet, int nItems)
```

should be replaced with:

```
public static double[] discount(double[] prices, boolean[] isPet, int nItems)
```

By the way, `discount` is never filled, it will return an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

The method signature is a compile-time promise between you and Java - you promise to return the type that you specify. `void` in a method signature implies you aren't going to return anything, yet you return something. That's a violation of the promise, hence the error.

You would have to change your method signature to merely return `double[]` to fulfill the promise to the compiler.

It's also the case that `discount` is never actually *filled*...assignment is right-to-left associative.  So, the statement `prices[x] = discount[n]` may not do what you expect it to.

Comment: can you point out where i can read up more about how to do the prices[x] = discount[n] statement and make it work the way i want it to?

Comment: wow nvm i just realized what you said... been thinking about it the wrong way.. thank you for point that out.